# Custom keyboard shortcut not executing service

Tags: keyboard, finder, services

I have a custom keyboard shortcut created for a finder service to compress selected files.

[image: From services list]

However despite working once or twice when I first created it, it has no effect now. The service works perfectly if I manually select it but not with the shortcut. As you can see from the screenshot the shortcut is definitely assigned...

Edit:

Just discovered that it actually works in all finder views except column view...

What's going on here?

Comment: I can also confirm that the services keyboard shortcuts are NOT working in column view (latest mac OS 10.11.6). Total fail.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this happens when there are conflicting keyboard shortcuts with other apps. Here is how I troubleshoot this type of problem.

1. Restart and [prevent all login items from running](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20716?viewlocale=en_US).
2. Try the shortcut you’ve assigned, in this case, `Option+Command+C`.
3. If it works, that means there are other apps that prevent you from running the service.
4. Run the apps in login items one by one and test the shortcut until you find the conflicting apps.

Most of time it solves my problem. If it’s not conflicting keyboard shortcuts form other apps, you might use [Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) to check the state of each key when pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I haven't had a chance to check that yet but I'm not sure it's being caught by something else as I've just discovered that it works in all finder views except column view... Only manually selecting the service will work in column view. Any ideas?